# Automatically regenerated .fuse_hidden928347928374 files when I try to delete my own

Tags: filesystem, ntfs, fuse

I have an NTFS volume mounted under linux, and periodically, after I've deleted a file of my own, a clone of it will appear in the directory where the actual file was.  I can usually delete this file, but it immediately comes back. If I try to run `rm -rf parent/`, it doesn't allow me to. I usually have to wait 20 minutes or so and go do other things before I can successfully delete the directory without the file being there.

What's going on here, and what can I do about it, since it's quite annoying.

Comment: What is the file you are trying to delete? Why do you want to delete the file? How do you know you can safely delete the file?

Comment: they're just user files.  not system ones.  they're on an external data-only volume.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. It happened because the file was open in VLC. I closed VLC, unmounted, mounted back, and I could delete the file. Make sure the original file isn't open in another program.